# Is this anti-pattern way of implementing arrays fatal in Firebase Database?

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firstly, I have read [Firebase Blog: Best Practices Arrays](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) and this is the anti-pattern structure in question [Anti-Pattern Array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh9Cn.png).

This is how the Anti-pattern array is coded:

```
database.child("\(groupChatId)_I/messages").runTransactionBlock ({ (currentData: MutableData) -> TransactionResult in

        guard var currentMessages = currentData.value as? [[String: Any]] else {
            completion(false)
            return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
        }
       
        ...


        // Define the message dimensions
        let messageIndex: [String: Any] = [
            "message_id": newMessageData.messageId,
            "message_type": newMessageData.kind.messageKindString,
            "message_content": message,
            "sender_name": myName,
            "message_date": dateString,
            "sender_email": mySafeEmail,
        ]
        currentMessages.append(messageIndex)
        
        currentData.value = currentMessages
        return TransactionResult.success(withValue: currentData)
    
    })
```

I am aware that arrays have been described as "evil", especially when multiple users attempt to edit the same array simultaneously. However, doesn't calling a runTransactionBlock prevent a mess from happening? If I understood it correctly, it kind of "locks" that database directory until the array modification is complete.

Do I need to worry about using this anti-pattern way of storing arrays? Please briefly include the following concepts when providing an answer: potential scalability issues, database cost bill and better way of storing ordered arrays (text messages).

I apologise in advance if I misused any terminologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a transaction can indeed prevent conflicts from multiple users from occurring. But when using transactions to update the messages in your screenshot there are two negative consequences:

1. To add a message, you'll need to run a transaction on the entire `messages` node. This means that you need to run al messages to add one message at the end, which adds overhead in the order of the number of messages for each call (and to your bill at some point too).
2. Transactions fail if the user is (temporarily or semi-permanently) not connected to the database backend. You'd be surprised how regularly a connection drop temporarily for mobile users.

As the blog post explains: to solve all these problems, use `push()` keys in your data model.